# Warehouse/Inventory software for Home usage

Tags: soho

I'm looking for Warehouse/Inventory software for Home usage. (not catalog software for movie collection)

Is there something like that?

Feature list

- photo/image attachments
- barcode support
- warehouse map (for better visualization, where is a item)

My first idea is not for insurance purposes, but it's one of the use cases. Next is for home larder or workroom.

Comment: What kind of wares (or is it warez?) would you like to store in it? Does it need to support images? Do you want to be able to print it or should it be accessible from anywhere else? Please add some more info!

Comment: By home, I'd assume he means a way to catalog physical possessions, possibly for insurance purposes.

Answer (score 4):

lifehacker - [Five Best Home Inventory Tools](http://lifehacker.com/5514470/five-best-home-inventory-tools)

Answer (score 1):

There's [Attic Manager](http://www.guacosoft.com/attic), it has photos and barcodes.

There is no graphical map, but locations can be nested, so you can create sections and sub-sections of warehouse(s). The depth is unlimited, so you can even label the shelves, boxes, etc. if you need it.